# Adobe Dreamweaver CS 5 HTML5

Tags: web, flash-cs5

I am new to web development.
I am a student and at the high school they have installed Adobe Dreamweaver CS 5 trial with some HTML 5 Extension/Update. I never used this program. I used to use notepad.  I was wondering if CS 5 with the mentioned update is enough to work in HTML 5.

I'm referring to the compatibility. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a bit of an opinion based question and there is no correct answer, however, from my bias, writing HTML is always best done in a text editor, it allows you the fine grain control and cross browser compatibility options that many visual editors fail to account for, and often fill up with unnecessary tags. I believe the dreamweaver HTML5 extensions will be enough however, although I'm unsure about some of the more advanced compatibilities.